# Is there in the world any strong optimizing compiler for a simple functional language to itself?

Tags: javascript, haskell, optimization, compiler-construction, scheme

Is there in the world any compiler for a simple functional language such as that defined [on this article](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.50.8424&rep=rep1&type=pdf), or maybe just Scheme or even ML for itself? That is, a compiler that will analyze the code for that said simple functional language, perform complicated optimizations such as **stream fusion** and return the optimized code?

The reason I need this is that I'm trying to compile my simple toy language (pretty much lambda calculus + numbers and arrays) to JavaScript, but as it is, it is extremely slow due to the fact that the naive compiler is completely unoptimized. Functions are not uncurried, things such as `(map f (map g h))` are not fused into `(map (f . g) h)`. Implementing an optimizing compiler would pose [much work](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.104.7401). I've thought in taking advantage of existing compilers such as GHC, but I've not decided how that would be possible. I could, for example, just compile my language to Haskell and compile it back to JavaScript, but most Haskell->JS solutions aren't optimal and produce tons of overhead. Such existing strong optimizing compiler for a simple functional language to itself would cut a lot of work. Is there any in the world?

Comment: Side note, since you plan on compiling to JavaScript: have you heard about Google's [Closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/)? It seems to perform pretty heavy inlining from JavaScript to JavaScript.

Comment: Yes and no, heavy is not an adjective you should use. Its optimizations are trivial. Not for its fault, though, many things simply can't be optimized in pure JS->JS. Stream Fusion is completely impossible.

Comment: [a case in point](https://gist.github.com/WillNess/8217144) (a test case for your future compiler/optimizer). Tangled list-based code (in Haskell) which really represents just one nested loop, using one temp array. -- Speaking of loops, are you familiar with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons) and [this](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-bin/techreports/TRNNN.cgi?trnum=TR19). It might be relevant (or just a historical background perhaps).

Comment: All those are very useful, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

GHC can produce GHC-Core, which is an intermediate primitive Haskell-like language. It is staged after all the optimizations of the compiler, including the advanced stuff like stream-fusion. So I guess it might be a perfect candidate for your task.

From [the docs](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/an-external-representation-for-the-ghc-core-language-for-ghc-6.10.html):

> The Glasgow Haskell Compiler (GHC) uses an intermediate language, called “Core,” as its internal program representation within the compiler’s simplification phase. Core resembles a subset of Haskell, but with explicit type annotations in the style of the polymorphic lambda calculus (Fω).
>
> GHC’s front-end translates full Haskell 98 (plus some extensions) into Core. The GHC optimizer then repeatedly transforms Core programs while preserving their meaning. A “Core Lint” pass in GHC typechecks Core in between transformation passes (at least when the user enables linting by setting a compiler flag), verifying that transformations preserve type-correctness. Finally, GHC’s back-end translates Core into STG-machine code [stg-machine] and then into C or native code.

Comment: Pardon, but if that is true, how was it never used by other languages to produce JavaScript from Haskell? I thought Haskell->JS was naturally handicapped because Haskell has lots of features and differences (such as laziness) that translate into MBs and MBs of overheads.

Comment: @Viclib I can't speak for the implementors of JS compilers. You might be interested in contacting the communities of popular modern Haskell-to-JS projects such as [Elm](http://elm-lang.org/) and [Fay](http://fay-lang.org/). Concerning laziness, you should be aware that even in Haskell it can't always be optimized away, that's why we have "Thunks" in runtime.

Comment: Haste compiles from STG to Javascript.  STG is one stage along from Core in the GHC pipeline.  https://github.com/valderman/haste-compiler

Comment: @TomEllis so bad after 3 hours of trying I couldn't compile Haste. Seems like it does not work on OSX.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in books, I can recommend Christian Queinnec's book *Lisp In Small Pieces* and Andrew Appel's series of books on compilers (one is called *Compiling with Continuations*, and there are two or three others about modern compilers with names that escape me at the moment). It's been a while since I read them, but I think both provide information about source-to-source compilation, and of course both cover various kinds of optimization. Any decent compiler textbook should have something to say that would be of interest to you.